# Get attribute and element values from xml in sql

Tags: sql, xml, attributes, element

I have the following XML and need to pull this data into a sql table to get the attribute name and all of the element values

```
 declare @GetQuoteXML xml
 set @GetQuoteXML = '<QuoteRequest>
 <QuoteRisk>
     <ChildControls parent = "MainPerson">
            <OccupationID>347</OccupationID>
            <OccupationDescription />
            <OccupationOtherDescription>accountant</OccupationOtherDescription>
        </ChildControls>
     <ChildControls parent = "OtherPerson">
            <OccupationID>200</OccupationID>
            <OccupationDescription />
            <OccupationOtherDescription>engineer</OccupationOtherDescription>
        </ChildControls>
</QuoteRisk>
</QuoteRequest>'
```

My SQL is

```
SELECT 
    AttributeName = ChildControls.value('(//ChildControls/@parent)[1]','varchar(50)'),
    NodeName = ChildControls.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    NodeValue = ChildControls.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM @GetQuoteXML.nodes('//ChildControls/*') AS ChildControlTable(ChildControls)
```

but the results always seem to be under the 'Mainperson' attribute, and doesnt return the 'OtherPerson' in the AttributeName column

```
AttributeName   NodeName                    NodeValue
MainPerson      OccupationID                347
MainPerson      OccupationDescription   
MainPerson      OccupationOtherDescription  accountant
MainPerson      OccupationID                200
MainPerson      OccupationDescription   
MainPerson      OccupationOtherDescription  engineer
```

What I want the results to look like is:

```
AttributeName   NodeName                    NodeValue
MainPerson      OccupationID                347
MainPerson      OccupationDescription   
MainPerson      OccupationOtherDescription  accountant
OtherPerson     OccupationID                200
OtherPerson     OccupationDescription   
OtherPerson     OccupationOtherDescription  engineer
```

I'm relatively new to this and can't seem to figure this one out, please help as this probably so simple to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT 
    AttributeName = ChildControls.value('../@parent','varchar(50)'),
    NodeName = ChildControls.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    NodeValue = ChildControls.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM @GetQuoteXML.nodes('//ChildControls/*') AS ChildControlTable(ChildControls)
```

RESULT:

[image]